# Import Test result to jira for cucumber tests

Tags: cucumber, mocha.js, spectron, jira-xray

I have Spectron project which outputs to junit reporter as result.xml file. I want to import the test results as test execution to the corresponding Test in Jira Ticket. Some of the Jira Tests are manual and others are cucumber tests.

the content of my result.xml is :

Firstly, after running my tests, I create a test execution using the following template

```
{
"fields": {
   "project":
   {
      "key": "SAN"
   },
   "summary": "$issueType from e2e",
   "description": "Automatically created $issueType while running e2e test",
   "issuetype": {
      "name": "$issueType"
   }
 }
}
```

Then, I try to import the result.xml to the created test execution ticket I already created, when importing the results for manual tests, new tickets will be created since a generic definition field is expected, this will happen only once (somehow I could live with that)

my Problem :

1. I have no clue how could I import the test results and link the test execution to the Cucumber-Jira Tickets.
2. What I aspire is that the manualy runned cucumber tests and the automated runned tests show links to the same cucumber test in Jira.
3. I can not find a cucumber reporter for mocha, which outputs in a format, that cucumber comfortable with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so after searching for a while I came to the result:

- Jira will create a test of type generic for each test case you have in your result, if Jira finds a generic test for the test case, it will add an execution result to the test
- if you want to have the e2e test results, you could write a plugin to show the results of manually executed cucumber tests with automatically executed results